# How To Add Hash To Slug in apostrophe-cms?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

Apostrophe-cms automaticlly convert hash (#) to (-) like below example  ,

My slug is 
/aboutdvld/dvldprofile/inspiringwords#anything

it's convert it automaticlly like this 
/aboutdvld/dvldprofile/inspiringwords-anything ?!

is there any way to solve this without making custom module !

thanks in advance

Comment: are you trying to trip the browser's hash anchor functionality?

Comment: i have jquery tabs and i want to run this functionality ! so i need to have in the browser div id with hash

Answer (score 0):

Since the webserver, by design, never sees the "#" part of a URL, it would be impossible for Apostrophe to serve a page with a "#" in its slug unless modified.

It sounds to me like you are trying to subdivide your page into tabs. However for SEO purposes it is still one page.

So the best approach would most likely be to create a singleton in your page template called "tabs" that is powered by a custom widget, which you'd define in a module called `tabs-widgets`. See [custom widgets](https://docs.apostrophecms.org/apostrophe/tutorials/getting-started/custom-widgets) in the Apostrophe documentation. The widget would have a `tabs` property of type `array` and each tab in the array would have `slug` and `label` fields.

You can then write a widget player (again, see that page of the documentation) which utilizes jQuery tabs or the tool of your choice to implement tab behavior, except when the user has editing permissions. You can account for that in your `widget.html` file by checking the `data.widget._edit` flag.

In `widget.html`, you would iterate over `data.widget.tabs` and output sub-areas for each one, using `data.widget` in place of the `data.page` object and passing `tab.slug` as the name. One catch there is that area names cannot contain hyphens, so you might want to write a nunjucks helper function to help convert them to camelCase:

```
// inside your module, server side index.js code in construct
self.addHelpers({
  camelName: function(s) {
    return self.apos.utils.camelName(s);
  }
});
```